# excel vba copy / pasting values losing precision

Tags: excel, vba, precision, numeric, paste

i'm using excel (microsoft 365 - 32-bit) and have a vba macro to open a source workbook, copy a range of cells and paste it to a target workbook ie the workbook containing this macro. The source cells contain formulas and I want to copy the results of those formulas.

The issue is that some of the values being pasted into the target workbook are losing 1 digit of precision.
The source values are a mix of formatted numbers and scientific numbers. Manually copying and pasting the data between workbooks works fine.

Some of the pasted values appear to be rounding whilst others are OK, for example:

-0.000153299 gets pasted as -0.000153299 [ok, no problem]

-4.57147E-05 gets pasted as -4.57147E-05 [ok, no problem]

-1.534989E-04 gets pasted as -1.534990E-04 [Rounding Issue]

-8.457692E-05 gets pasted as -8.457690E-05 [Rounding Issue]

1.110385E-03 gets pasted as 1.110385E-03 [ok, no problem]

here is the vba code doing the copying/pasting operation:

```
    Workbooks.Open (file)
    Worksheets("Output_Data").Activate

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lcol = Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(lrow, lcol)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").UsedRange.Clear
    Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Any hints to avoid losing numerical precision?

thanks

I was expecting no change in the pasted values.

Comment: Are you really loosing precision or is it a matter of displaying the value (numberformat)

Comment: it is losing precision. This is verified by clicking on the target workbook cell and looking at the value displayed in the formula bar.

Comment: It is not necessary to use cut and paste.  You can assign the values directly DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value.  There are many examples if you google.

Comment: Please provide the actual value as shown in the formula bar, for "OK" and "not OK" copy/paste examples.